# How to find a word in a line starting with a specific string in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following example data in Notepad++:

```
ES value="tren";
FR value="train";
EN value="train";
PT value="tren";
DE value="Zug";
```

I want to select and replace the "train" word in the line starting with "EN". Can I do that with RegEx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer from #Wiktor Stribiżew, I managed it this way:

**Search:** `^(EN\s.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])Train([^a-zA-Z0-9].*)$`

Details:

- `^` Start of a line
- `EN\s` "EN" followed by a space
- `.*` Anything
- `[^a-zA-Z]` The last caracter before the word must not be a letter, this is to avoid replacing the word in cases such as "cons**train**t"
- `Train`the word looked for
- The rest of the line follows the same logic, except for `$`, which is just indicating the end of the line.

**Replace:** `\1Boat\2`

Details:

- `\1` and `\2` are referring to the parenthesis groups from the search above. So I am leaving the result of the search of the parenthesis as it is, only modifying the "Train" part.

I am not sure why the syntax of the other answer did not work for me in Notepad++, but this worked.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You may use

*Find what*: `^(EN\h.*")train(";)$`
*Replace with*: `$1NEW_WORD$2`

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(EN\h.*")`  - Group 1 capturing `EN`, a horizontal whitespace, then any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible up to the last `"`...
- `train` - a literal `train` substring
- `(";)$` - `";` at the end of the line.

[image]

Comment: @MYGz: There are a lot of ways to get what OP needs. I prefer the most verbose way when there no specific criteria given. Yes, `(?<=EN value=")(train)` will work, but it will also match in `FREN value="trainMENOW`

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. However, it seems not to be working. I get a "Can't find the text". A activated the "Regular expression" option at the bottom of the window.

Comment: Did you select *Regular expression* mode?

Comment: Try removing the `$`. Maybe there are trailing whitespace symbols.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131790/discussion-between-frouil-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Sorry, the problem is somewhere on your side: either with the text you have (you may check what symbols there are at http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/) or with the options.